# Why use scala repl instead of worksheet?

Tags: scala, ide, read-eval-print-loop

Why use the scala repl instead of a scala worksheet ?

The worksheet evaluates expressions line by line as does the repl and offers a nice GUI.

Are there any advantages to using the scala repl instead of worksheet ?

Comment: First of all, REPL were here long before worksheet. REPL can be invoked in two seconds in console -- to use worksheet you need to have IDE up and running.

Comment: just to add some more reasons: REPL (console scala) can be easily invoked from a remote computer (invoking IDE would much more complicated), speed (console app is much more faster), if you are not using IDE, REPL is the only possibility,...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where there's Scala there's REPL. The worksheet is currently only available in Scala IDE and the early access and nightly's of Idea.

REPL is fast and can also be invoked from inside an SBT session by typing `console`

Comment: You can find the worksheet feature in the latest stable versions of the Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA as well: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/04/scala-worksheet/

Comment: Also, in the REPL you have the automatically assigned variables res0, res1, etc. Not a big thing to add variables in the worksheet, but I always enjoyed the exploratory nature of getting some potentially useful intermediate result in, say, res42, and then transforming it further without having to assign it to anything.